# Run spark job in multiple nodes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im trying to run a sample spark job and its working fine.Now, I need to run the same job in multiple nodes in a cluster.
What needs to be changed in my program to indicate to run it in multiple nodes.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

#conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("hadoop-master").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

#lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/user/hduser/gutenberg/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option needed change in code is master of spark context. To run script on hadoop you need to place `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in the environment and set master to `yarn`. All of this is explained in documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#launching-spark-on-yarn

Comment: Thanks. I was able to run on spark cluster..I have a spark cluster and hadoop cluster setup..Is there any advantage on running a spark job in spark cluster vs hadoop cluster?

Comment: It depends on your needs. On hadoop claster you can create as many spark jobs as you wish and this works nicely with multiuser environment. For example permissions to HDFS/Hive data and YARN resources are managed for each user's job using standard Hadoop mechanisms. But it you are the only one using spark, maintainitng hadoop cluster only for spark jobs may be unnecessary overhead.